# nodeJS - express shall deliver the referring main.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote a nodeJS server with express and I want it to deliver the index.html and the refering main.js. It only delivers the index.html, both files are in the same directory:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't serve other files than `index.html`.

If you want to serve static files in a directory, the simplest solution is to use `express.static` :

```
app.use (express.static(__dirname));
```